# VBA Excel: Sort range with alphabetic order

Tags: excel, vba

> Error 1004: the range object cannot be excuted.

[image: error 1004]

Hello Gurus, I'm a newbee in Excel VBA. I just try to add automatic sorting with alphabatic order to all my worksheets in a workbook. At most worksheets, the following code works perfect. But at several worksheets in this workbook, it doesn't und returns the runtime error as the screenshot shows. I can't figure out why, really strange.The worksheets have the simplest exact same structures. Thanks a lot!

```
Dim r As Integer
Dim c As Integer

r = ActiveCell.Row
c = ActiveCell.Column
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheets(17).Select


Range("A8:E30").Select
Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("A8"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo, _
    OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
    DataOption1:=xlSortNormal


Cells(r, c).Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: First of all, concatenate selection and sorting as `Range("A8:E30").Sort ...`, this will help to get rid of declaration of `r` and `c` and `r = ActiveCell.Row: c = ActiveCell.Column` plus `Cells(r, c).Select`. Second, do you need to activate sheet every time? If you change value of the sheet (with another macro for example) while you're at another sheet, you will be moved to the changed sheet. Instead you can reference this `Worksheet` as `Worksheet("sheetname").Range("A8:E30").Sort ...` or use `With Worksheet("sheetname") ... End With`.

Comment: If you implement the suggestions made by @AntiDrondert, the following comment won't be relevant .... Is `Sheets(17)` actually the sheet that you are expecting?  `Sheets(17)` means the 17th sheet **in tab order**, which is not necessarily `Tabelle17`.

Comment: AntiDrondert, thanks for the response.  With your suggestion, I simplified the code as: 

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Cells(8, 1).Select
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Range("A8:E30").Sort Key1:=Range("A9"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo, _
OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
    
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

It works now. Thanks.

Comment: YowE3K, thanks for reply. Beause there is some asian words as name of each worksheet, I cannot type them in the code, so I just take the worksheet order to identiy them in the code.

Although it works now, I still cannot understand, why the code before doesn't work at some worksheets, but at others. After the error message, the worksheet jumps to the next. I guess it's selection errror, but cannot figure out the reason.

Comment: @P.Schlegel Instead of using the worksheet's tab index (i.e. `Sheets(17).`) or its `Name` (i.e. `Sheets("WI_FAasian characters").`) you can also refer to a sheet by its `CodeName` (i.e. `Tabelle17.`).  But if this code is in the code module of the sheet itself, you can just not qualify your ranges and they will default to the sheet that the code is in (unlike normal code which defaults to whatever sheet is currently active).  The code you posted in a comment doesn't qualify the `Range` objects, so I believe that will get around the issue.